# How to highlight a column in a table layout based on current date

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: Table Layout]

I have a table layout of 9*6 in which i have a row of week days(Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun). How can i highlight that specific field(i.e.Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun)based on current day or date.**Suppose if today is Monday, Monday column has to be highlighted and if it is Friday, Friday column has to be highlighted, and so on based on current date.** How can i code this?Any reference links that i can look into.Thank you.

EDIT: I am able to get the day of the week by using `DayOfWeek dof = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek();` 
Can anyone tell me how to highlight the column?

Comment: Can you show us your efforts ?

Comment: Which API levels does your app support?

Comment: Minimum API level 21-22 and i am currently running it on API 28 @deHaar

Comment: I have included my table layout in the question

Comment: You have to determine what day of week *today* is, right? You could have done it with `java.time`, which is directly available for Android API level 26 and above but you have to use a [backport library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) for lower API levels.

Comment: could you please elaborate i am new to android studio and java. And after determining the day , the day column must be highlighted. How to code this? @deHaar

Comment: I can't tell you how to highlight your view elements, that's what you have to do yourself, but I can tell you how to find the current day of week: `DayOfWeek dof = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek();` and then you can `switch (dof)` and provide a `case` for each of the seven possibilities. Should work directly in Android 26+.

Comment: Thank you...it helped a lot @deHaaar

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<String> weekDaysList; //assign required days
  String dayToBeHighlighted; //get Day of the week
  int indexOfDay = weekDaysList.indexOf(dayToBeHighlighted);

  if(indexOfDay >-1){
     for(int i=0; i<numOfRows;i++){
         TableRow row = (TableRow)tblLayout.getChildAt(i);
         for(int j=0;j<numOfColumns;j++){
             //view or other layout/button etc.            
             View highlight = (View)row.getChildAt(indexOfDay);
             break;
         }
        }
      }
```

Comment: can you explain this more clearly? I mean what this code does? @Naveen Avidi

Comment: It highlights the cells/child views as you wanted ! If you want it much clearer, post your code l. Then I'll modify it.

Comment: does it highlight the entire column?